# No javascript support

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hi is there a way we can use HTML 5 features without using a javascript. Say for example I want to use the geolocation feature of HTML 5 but the user turned off it's javascript.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use JS when there is no JS.
If the specific thing you need requires only HTML tags - no problem

Answer (score 1):

Geolocation is this: http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/

It's an API which means that it's meant to be used by a programming language - specifically JavaScript.

Note that Geolocation is not an HTML 5 feature.

And - to answer your question - no, you cannot use the Geolocation API without JavaScript (or some other programming language).